# How would I defer react-ga4 on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, google-analytics, pagespeed

I have google analytics set up on my MERN application using react-ga4. It works well but is a real hit to my page load speed in production. I want to defer the firing of it but I can't find a method that works.

**My Code (Only implementation of google analytics in my application):**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
//import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
import App from "./App";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import {NextUIProvider} from '@nextui-org/react'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";

//const ReactGA = loadable(() => import('react-ga4'));
const delay = () => import(`mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css`)
setTimeout(() => delay(), 100)

// const ReactGA = loadable(() =>
//   pMinDelay(import('react-ga4'), 200)
  
// )

//ReactGA.initialize('G-N7R0LNZN57')

//ReactGA.initialize('G-N7R0LNZN57');


const queryClient = new QueryClient()

ReactDOM.render(
  
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
         <NextUIProvider>
         
        <BrowserRouter>
         
          
          <App />
          
          
        </BrowserRouter>
          
          </NextUIProvider>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider> 
         , 
  document.getElementById("root"),
  function() {
    ReactGA.initialize('G-N7R0LNZN57');
  }
);


reportWebVitals(console.log);
```

Comment: Try lazy loading using React.lazy()

Comment: It causes there to be no data flow to google analytics dashboard

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Rohil no i didnt, any delay causes the analytics not to work but it is still blocking the main thread for 80 ish ms